# Converting Access PIVOT query to SQL Server

Tags: sql, pivot, transform

```
TRANSFORM Sum(QUANTIDADE) AS SumOfQUANTIDADE
SELECT SUPERVISOR, Sum(QUANTIDADE) AS Total
FROM REPORTING
WHERE (((REPORTING.FAMILIA)="TESTE1" Or (REPORTING.FAMILIA)="TESTE2" In (select [00 - Max Data Report].[MaxOfCODMES_REPORT] from [00 - Max Data Report])))
GROUP BY COORDENADOR, SUPERVISOR
ORDER BY COORDENADOR
PIVOT Val([COD_DIA]);
```

**Result**:

| Supervisor | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Supervisor1 | 43 | 55 | 12 | 81 |
| Supervisor2 | 31 | 22 | 43 | 23 |
| Supervisor3 | 54 | 67 | 77 | 55 |
| Supervisor4 | 42 | 22 | 11 | 56 |

I am trying to convert this query to sql server. the above is the result from the query in access. the column headers are the months which are included in the cod_dia column from the table in the server. if we are in the end of the month then it would input the 31 columns for example.

```
select * from ( 
          select  SUPERVISOR,Sum(QUANTIDADE) AS Total 
                  FROM REPORTING 
                           where  FAMILIA='TESTE1' or FAMILIA='TESTE2' In (select [MaxOfCODMES_REPORT] from [00 - Max Data Report ESALES]) group by supervisor,coordenador) t pivot (Sum(QUANTIDADE) for QUANTIDADE in (cod_dia)) as p
```

i tried this in sql server but it says it doesn't recognise "Quantidade" in the last line, but it should because if select that column from that database it shows that column. Unless, of course, i am doing something wrong in the query

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'QUANTIDADE'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'QUANTIDADE'.
```

Comment: Can you please share the structure of your table?

Comment: i have already made the query quite some time ago. i will post here the solution. thnk you